# Selection of Bootstrap switch group

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, bootstrap-switch

There are many switches in my table, so I want to switch(on/off) every switch separately. But in here when I switch some one it affect for the all i think that is dues to it's `class`. please tell me how to work with each switch without effecting to others,

this is the switch group 
[image]

```
    function load_saved_exam_data() {
        var tableData = '';
        jQuery.post('<?php echo site_url("administrator/active_exam_c/load_activate_exams") ?>', function (e) {
            if (e === undefined || e.length === 0 || e === null) {
                tableData += '<tr><th colspan="8" class="alert alert-warning text-center"> -- No Data Found -- </th></tr>';
                jQuery('.activate_exam_tbl tbody').html('').append(tableData);
            } else {
                jQuery.each(e, function (index, qData) {
//                    alert(qData.act_status);
                    var checked;
                    if (qData.act_status == 1) {
                        checked = 'checked';
                    } else {
                        checked = '';
                    }

                    index++;
                    tableData += '<tr>';
                    tableData += '<td>' + index + '</td>';
                    tableData += '<td>' + qData.exam_name + '</td>';
                    tableData += '<td>' + qData.start_date + '</td>';
                    tableData += '<td>' + qData.end_date + '</td>';
                    tableData += '<td>' + qData.ex_session_id + '</td>';
                    tableData += '<td><div class="btn-group">'
                            + '<div class="onoffswitch"><input type="checkbox" onclick="handleClick(this);" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" value="' + qData.exm_id + '" id="myonoffswitch" ' + checked + ' ><label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch"><span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span><span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span></label></div></div></td>';
                    tableData += '<td><div class="btn-group"><button class="btn btn-danger delete_exam_act"  value="' + qData.exm_id + '"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;Remove</button></div></td>';
                    tableData += '</tr>';
                });

                jQuery('.activate_exam_tbl tbody').html('').append(tableData);
            }
        }, "json");
    }



    function handleClick(cb) {
        var activation_val = jQuery(cb).val();
        var activation_checked;
        if (cb.checked) {
            activation_checked = '1';
        } else {
            activation_checked = '0';
        }
        var data = {
            activation_val: activation_val,
            activation_checked: activation_checked

        };
        jQuery.post('<?php echo site_url("administrator/active_exam_c/update_exam_activation") ?>', data, function (d) {
//            console.log(d);
            if (d.status == 1) {
                swal("success!", "Successfully Updated!", "success");

            } else {
                swal("Only one exam can be activated..", "Please deactivate active exam and try again!", "warning");

            }
        }, 'json');
    }
```

This switch is working with `css`

```
.onoffswitch {
    position: relative; width: 90px;
    -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox {
    display: none;
}

.onoffswitch-label {
    display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 20px;
}

.onoffswitch-inner {
    display: block; width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;
    -moz-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s; -webkit-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -o-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s; transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
    display: block; float: left; width: 50%; height: 30px; padding: 0; line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px; color: white; font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before {
    content: "ACTIVE";
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #2FCCFF; color: #FFFFFF;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:after {
    content: "NOT ACTIVE";
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE; color: #999999;
    text-align: right;
}

.onoffswitch-switch {
    display: block; width: 18px; margin: 6px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 20px;
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 56px;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
    right: 0px; 
}
```

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: @FrankerZ code included

Comment: Where in the code are you switching the value? `console.log(checked)` and make sure you're seeing some 'checked' values, and some '' values.

Comment: @FrankerZ this switch is working with css